# How to update an ISO image using Jigdo?

Tags: jigdo

I am trying to update the ISO image of Ubuntu using Jigdo . Can any one explain the exact way to do this ?

Comment: Which ISO are you trying to update?  A quick check of a random server from the CD mirrors list (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) shows that in general only the Ubuntu Server images have Jigdo control files available for them.  Desktop images for Ubuntu cannot be updated using Jigdo currently.  Xubuntu and Kubuntu do not offer use of Jigdo as an option and Lubuntu only offers it as an option for their alternate installer.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat 13.10 64-bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jigdo only works with non-live images. Since Ubuntu dropped the Ubuntu Alternate image, the only image that will work with Jigdo is the Ubuntu Server image.  Even then that image is now using some kind of live image to make installation faster so Jigdo won't be nearly as efficient as before.  If you're just looking for ways to minimize the amount of data needed to update a 13.10 64-bit image, you're probably best to use zsync as it seems to be the most efficient way to do delta based updates of the live images.

Comment: what's meant by 'Alternate image'?

Comment: @VarunDas that was a non-live version, a text based installation like Debian's.